# Multiple validation error message on using pattern, maxlength and required. I want to show only one custom error not three different errors

Tags: html, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I am working on bootstrap 4 and using the following code to replace the error message.

```
 <input type="text" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}" maxlength="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User No." required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid User No.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

**However I am getting three errors.**

1. **'Please enter valid User No.'** on clicking the submit button.
2. **'Please match the requested format'** and **'Please enter valid User No.'** on 
    clearing using backspace.
3. **'Please fill out the Field'** on clearing all text.

**What I want.**

1. **Errors to show only on clicking the submit button.**[This is working right 
   now].
2. **Not to show any errors while using backspace to clear contents or else show a single error message throughout.**

```css
.jumbotron-m-color {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #e8e4db;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a6c1ee 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
}

.form-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15vh;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  background-color: #f4fdfd;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron-m-color container-fluid ">


  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <form id="Login-form" class="form-container">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User No.</label>


          <input type="text" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{5}" maxlength="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User No." required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter valid User No.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
          <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1" style="font-size:small;">Remember me</label>
                    </span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-color btn-block">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: You mean the whole html??

Comment: yes in a code snippet please it will be appreciated

Comment: I have added the code.